# Counters and accumulators not working and making the program crash. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, counter, accumulator

I've been toying around with this code for some hours now and even though simple I cannot find what is wrong with it. IS it the logic? OR the problem is a syntax-related one?

I want the program to ask the user to enter a number indicating how many kilometres they've run individuately in races this month.
The program will tell them on average how much they've run in each race.

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 main () 
{
   int STOP_VALUE = 8 ; /* you pick this number - outside the valid data set */

   int avg;
   int currentItem;
   float runningTotal = 0 ;
   int counterOfItems = 0 ;

   printf("Enter first item or 8 to stop: ");

   scanf("%d", &currentItem);

   while ( currentItem != 8) {

          runningTotal += currentItem;

      ++counterOfItems;

      printf("Enter next item or 8 to stop: ");
      scanf("%d", currentItem);      

}

   /* protect against division by 0 */
   if ( counterOfItems != 0 )
     {

          avg = runningTotal / counterOfItems ;}
     else {



   printf("On average, you've run %f per race and you've participated in %f running events. Bye! \n", runningTotal, counterOfItems);
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop

```
  scanf("%d", currentItem);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d", &currentItem);
             ^^
```

That said, `main ()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standard for a hosted environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your avg variable is an int, its going to be rounded, you could end up with some strange results.

Actually an update, your avg variable isn't used.